# Meteor / Iron router - Get parent data in an {{#each}} loop

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Considering:

```js
Template.tasks.helpers({
    equals: function() {
        // var data = ?
        return data.test == this;
    }
});
```

And:

```html
<template name="tasks">
    <ul>
    {{#each elements}}
        <li>
            {{this}} {{#if equals}}Equals!{{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

And for example:

```js
Router.route('tasks', {
    data: function () {
        var example = {
            test: 42,
            elements: [1, 2, 42, 100]
        }
        return example;
    }
});
```

**How can I get the parent data context** (the one passed on iron router's `route()` method with the data field) ?

In the example above, how can we display *42 - Equals!* ?

Comment: Using the `data` function is a bit of an anti pattern. Usually the template can be self contained rather than depending on the router. If you need to use the data fn, can you confirm if you are waiting for data from the server or if you are actually defining the data in your data function? If it is the former, then your data might just not have arrived when `equals` run. Try adding `if data` to your fn and it will rerun when your data is available.

Comment: You got it! :) Data was not ready...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Template.parentData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata):

```
Template.tasks.helpers({
    equals: function() {
        var data = Template.parentData();
        return data.test == this;
    }
});
```

Here is a live example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/LHxyDYkmNQB9H2Ezy/ParentData

Comment: Oops, it actually works! (As did my `Template.instance().data;` in the example). It wasn't working locally as contrary to the example I've a collection which was not ready. Fixed it thanks to @datacarl 's comment

Comment: Great. For completeness, I created a meteorpad example to reference.

Comment: Cool! It's nothing but I'd put `path: '/'` in the route on the meteorpad ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only way, but I've found a solution using `..` in the template:

```
<template name="tasks">
    <ul>
    {{#each elements}}
        <li>
            {{this}} {{#if equals ..}}Equals!{{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

And then:

```
Template.tasks.helpers({
    equals: function(parentData) {
        return parentData.test == this;
    }
});
```